# How to get a Rails App Deployed with Puma and Capistrano to start on reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, puma, systemd

I've managed to successfully deploy a Rails 4, Puma, Nginx App using Capistrano. When I deploy `cap production deploy` everything works great. My problem is if the server reboots for whatever reason or if it crashes, it doesn't restart.

I'm using a Debian 8 on DigitalOcean. It seems Debian 8 uses `systemd`, so I've followed the instructions from [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md) but it didn't work. After some research I've found a couple more scripts and the one that seemed most sensible was this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rails-Puma Webserver

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/apps/myapp
ExecStart=/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/systemd_rails server -e production
TimeoutSec=15
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've saved the above file in `/etc/systemd/system/rails-puma.service` then I've enabled it: `sudo systemctl enable rails.service` and finally started it: `sudo systemctl start rails-puma.service`

Which unfortunately didn't work. This is the result of `sudo systemctl status rails-puma.service`:

```
    ● rails-puma.service - Rails-Puma Webserver
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rails-puma.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2016-07-07 12:11:58 EDT; 4s ago
  Process: 4373 ExecStart=/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/systemd_rails server -e production (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 4373 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jul 07 12:11:58 mrcProd systemd[1]: rails-puma.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 07 12:11:58 mrcProd systemd[1]: Unit rails-puma.service entered failed state.
Jul 07 12:11:58 mrcProd systemd[1]: rails-puma.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jul 07 12:11:58 mrcProd systemd[1]: Failed to start Rails-Puma Webserver.
Jul 07 12:11:58 mrcProd systemd[1]: Unit rails-puma.service entered failed state.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=149425) can be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately not... I've been trying all sorts of combination but can't anything to work...

Comment: Is there any useful information in your puma error log file?

Comment: There's a `/var/myapp/current/log/puma.error` file which doesn't show anything related to starting/stop. I guess this file wouldn't be used if the application is not running but I don't know where the log for systemd are located though...

Comment: Perhaps [debugging options](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Systemd_problems) may help you. Also, what happends if you run manually `/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/systemd_rails server -e production` ?

Comment: 1) I'm looking at debugging options now. Here's the outcome of above command: `-bash: /home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/systemd_rails: No such file or directory`. Please note the app is being deploy by Capistrano and I'm using RVM. Also, this command from my app directory does work: `bundle exec puma -w4 -e production --preload -b unix://tmp/sockets/MRCbe-puma.sock`

Comment: 2) If I add this command: `bundle exec puma -w4 -e production --preload -b unix://tmp/sockets/MRCbe-puma.sock` into the service it doesn't work but it does work from `/home/myuser/apps/myapp/current`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar service but I declared slightly different `/etc/systemd/system/puma.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma Control
After=network.target auditd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/puma/puma-start
ExecStop=/etc/puma/puma-stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then in `/etc/puma/puma-start`

```
#!/bin/bash -

cd /home/changeuser/apps/changeapp/current && ( export RACK_ENV="production" ; /home/changeuser/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec puma -C /home/changeuser/apps/changeapp/shared/puma.rb --daemon )
```

and in `/etc/puma/puma-stop`

```
#!/bin/bash -

cd /home/changeuser/apps/changeapp/current && ( export RACK_ENV="production" ; /home/changeuser/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec pumactl -S /home/changeuser/apps/changeapp/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state stop )
```

remember after setting up to execute

```
chmod +x /etc/puma/puma-start
chmod +x /etc/puma/puma-stop
systemctl enable puma
```

and then to test

```
systemctl start puma
systemctl stop puma
systemctl restart puma
systemctl status puma
```

Comment: Just an update on the current state of many existing gems to handle startup and process management. 

It seems that development of capistrano-foreman, foreman, and RVM/Rubygems/Bundler have slowed and gem dependencies have not kept up. My after playing with those for a while, I decided to go this route for a manual install and it proved to be the cleanest and quickest way.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04 I was running into issues with CD and export in puma-start/stop, so I'm using: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec puma -C /home/deployer/apps/app_name/shared/config/puma.rb --daemon
 which appears to be loading in production.